# Offline web application with rewritten URL's

Tags: .htaccess, application-cache, service-worker

Using the Application Cache I can easily make my web application available offline and it works perfectly. The problem I am encountering is that I have recently started using a `.htaccess` file to rewrite urls from

> http://www.example.com/?/page

to

> http://www.example.com/page

After loading the 'homepage' in principal everything still works (as all pages are loaded through Ajax), but local bookmarks and the like do not work. Is there any way to add this functionality with a simple service worker, whilst still relying on the Application Cache for the rest of the offline functionality (thus allowing Firefox and Safari to fall back on the Application Cache, whilst Chrome and Opera would work perfectly offline).

Comment: To the downvoter, care to elaborate why you downvoted this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers that support service workers* use the presence of a service worker as a trigger to disable App Cache functionality for pages under the service worker's scope. See [Is Service Worker intended to replace or coexist with Appcache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271843/is-service-worker-intended-to-replace-or-coexist-with-appcache)

I understand how using a service worker for something like rewriting URLs is independent from the offline use case, and therefore shouldn't interfere with App Cache, but there's no flag that you can use to say "Hey, this is a service worker that plays nicely with App Cache, so let me use both."

** This applies to Google Chrome. As other browsers add support for service workers, they might have different policies with regard to App Cache.*

Comment: Ah, that does indeed explain a lot of what I saw in my own testing. Quite sad to hear there is no way for them to run at the same time (till the appcache is deprecated entirely) even though I agree the Application Cache is by far the inferior solution.